# How do I cite author in LaTeX?

Tags: bibtex, citing

How do I cite authors in LaTeX?

I tried using `natbib` package

---- `doc.tex` ----

```
...
\usepackage{natbib}
...
\citeauthor{736184}
...
```

---- `doc.bib` ----

```
@inproceedings{736184,
     author = {Broder, Andrei Z.},
...
```

but all I get is **(author?)** (in bold).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

At a bare minimum, your LaTeX source file needs to contain these elements for `\citeauthor` to work:

---- `doc.tex` ----

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
    \citeauthor{goossens93}

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{doc}
\end{document}
```

---- `doc.bib` ----

```
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

The correct compilation cycle for the document is then as follows:

```
latex doc
bibtex doc
latex doc
latex doc
```

The first compilation generates the list of cited works for BibTeX.  Then BibTeX uses that information to generate a `.bbl` file from `doc.bib` containing all of the citations formatted according to the bibliography style you choose.  The second compilation incorporates the `.bbl` into the document, and the third compilation updates all of the cross-references (e.g. citations).

Here is the output for the example above:

[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: **plainnat** was my problem. I didn't know that natbib uses different styles. I used **alpha** and I should have used **alphanat**. Unfortunately I do not have alphanat.bst and I couldn't find the file on internet (though the page you indicated says it provided by default). Do you know where to get it from?

Also for some reason I don't see the indexes (eg. [4]) when using plainnat. Why?

Comment: Whoops, there is no alphanat.bst--I've fixed the Wikibooks article (I wrote the table of natbib-compatible styles ;-) ).  I believe plainnat.bst is the style you're looking for--the *plain* and *alpha* citation format appears to be the same, it's just that in the bibliography, *plain* uses numbers for the cross-references, whereas *alpha* uses abbreviated last names and two-digit years.  natbib defaults to author-year cross-references, but it can also do numerical cross-references if you use "\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}" instead of "\usepackage{natbib}"

Comment: I still have some problems obtaining numbers in the biography!

instead of

[4] Author, Title,

I get only

Author, Title

I tried \usepackage[numbers]{natbib} and "plainnat" with no success.

Comment: I've updated my example and included an image of the output.  I hope that will help you track down your problem.

Comment: The same thing also happens when using other bibliography styles. For exaple, using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` with command `\citeauthor{some_id}` produces **(author?)**, whereas using `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` with `\citeauthor{some_id}` produces the desired result.