# Name of the author to appear in the text

Tags: bibliographies

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm using `abbrv` as `bibliographystyle`. I want to to refer to a paper in the middle of the sentence and I want the name of the author to appear in the text as well. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I cite author in Latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69379/how-do-i-cite-author-in-latex) (changing the `plainnat` to `abbrvnat` in the first answer should work)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `natbib` package with the `abbrvnat` style, and then citing with `\citet{CitationKey}` (includes the year), or `\citeauthor{CitationKey}`.

There is also the `apacite` package that let you cite authors with `\citeA{CitationKey}`, or `\shortciteA{CitationKey}`, and you will get the author name and the year in your text.