# citeauthor doesn't yield author name

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, latexmk

I would like to generate author citations in my text, and I have been following the information in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69381/33219).

I've got my includes

```
\usepackage[numbers,
                        sort&compress
                        ]{natbib}       % Sort numerical keys for multiple cites

\section{Example Chapter}

~\citeauthor{born_population_2003}
~\cite{born_population_2003}
```

I've got my bib file (with standard citations being referenced correctly)

```
@article{born_population_2003,
        title = {Population substructure of North Atlantic minke whales (Balaenoptera acutorostrata) inferred from regional variation of elemental and stable isotopic signatures in tissues},
        volume = {43},
        issn = {09247963},
        url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S092479630300085X},
        doi = {10.1016/S0924-7963(03)00085-X},
        number = {1-2},
        urldate = {2013-08-28},
        journal = {Journal of Marine Systems},
        author = {Born, {E.W.} and Outridge, P. and Riget, {F.F.} and Hobson, {K.A.} and Dietz, R. and Øien, N. and Haug, T.},
        month = sep,
        year = {2003},
        pages = {1--17},
        file = {born2003_1-s2.0-S092479630300085X-main.pdf:/home/ryan/.mozilla/firefox/hauwprbq.default/zotero/storage/PMNU4J6G/born2003_1-s2.0-S092479630300085X-main.pdf:application/pdf}
        }
```

But I'm not sure how I should check the compilation part. I'm using a template provided by my university, which is using a `Makefile`, which uses `latexmk` to compile the document

```
default:
        #latexmk -jobname=$(builddir) -pdfdvi thesis.tex
        latexmk -pdfdvi thesis.tex
```

The output I'm getting looks like this

[image]

Is this some issue with `latexmk`?

Comment: Might you be missing a closing curly brace in the entry?

Comment: You mean with the `~/citeauthor{author_key}`? I just checked that, and it looks like that is fine (now added to my include example at the beginning. Thanks!

Comment: You need to code the non-ascii characters in your bibtex file: e.g. Ø should be `{\O}` etc.

Comment: As moewe says, your bib entry is missing a final `}`.

Comment: The final `}` was just copy-paste problem. I'm guessing that Andrew is onto something here. I'll report once I verify that.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745/5001 for (much) more information on writing "accented" characters for use with BibTeX.