# How do I cite author in LaTeX with BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, zotero, better-bibtex

It's not the same question as [How do I cite author in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69379/how-do-i-cite-author-in-latex).

I create my `bib` file with Zotero (better BibLaTeX) and so I don't have `year` and `publisher` but `date` and `journaltitle` and so I can't use `\citeauthor` as proposed in the previous link.

I can use better BibTex but it seems that BibLaTeX is better than BibTex. Is there any other solution?

Edit: I used `Bibtex` thinking I used `Biblatex`
I had to install `biber` (Ubuntu)

```
apt-get install biber
```

And here is the scheme I use:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    sorting=none,
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\cite{pssh}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\cite{hsim2}.
    \citeauthor{hsim2}
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

`biblatex-examples.bib` is an extract from the file provided by `Zotero`

```
@article{pssh,
  title = {On the Mathematical Status of the Pseudo-Steady State Hypothesis of Biochemical Kinetics},
  volume = {1},
  timestamp = {2017-06-16T20:19:49Z},
  number = {1},
  urldate = {2017-06-01},
  journal = {Mathematical Biosciences},
  author = {Heineken, F. G. and Tsuchiya, H. M. and Aris, R.},
  year = {1967},
  keywords = {asymptotic solution,singular perturbation,steady-state},
  pages = {95--113},
  annote = {Explication "biologique" et math{\'e}matique que l'hypoth{\`e}se de quasy steady state.
Construction de la solution asymptotique pour tout t},
  file = {qss.pdf:/home/cecilelocal/.zotero/zotero/ekuhyidl.default/zotero/storage/RU83AENU/qss.pdf:application/pdf}
}

@article{hsim2,
  title = {{{HSIM}}: {{A Hybrid Stochastic Simulation System}} for {{Systems Biology}}},
  volume = {313},
  issn = {15710661},
  shorttitle = {{{HSIM}}},
  doi = {10.1016/j.entcs.2015.04.016},
  language = {en},
  timestamp = {2017-06-19T17:34:45Z},
  urldate = {2017-06-15},
  journal = {Electronic Notes in Theoretical Computer Science},
  author = {Amar, Patrick and Paulev{\'e}, Lo{\"\i}c},
  year = {2015},
  keywords = {circadian clock,entiy-centered systems,hybrid systems,simulation,stochastic simulations},
  pages = {3--21},
  annote = {Description de deux m{\'e}thodes de simulations : entit{\'e}-centr{\'e}e et SSA global},
  file = {hsim2.pdf:/home/cecilelocal/.zotero/zotero/ekuhyidl.default/zotero/storage/5KRMSRJU/hsim2.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

To obtain the `pdf` file I have to run

```
pdflatex name.tex
biber name
pdflatex name.tex
pdflatex name.tex
```

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is not very clear. There exist `\citeauthor` and  `\citeauthor*` commands in `biblatex`, so why can't you use them?

Comment: Ok... I understand... I used `bibtex` thinking I used `Biblatex`

Comment: I have retagged your question since you use BibTeX and not `biblatex`.

Comment: No, my question was about `Biblatex` and I have my answer, I was wrong. And now, it's good, because I found the information.

Comment: @Bernard Do you want to write up an answer? Or do you know a good duplicate. [How do I cite author in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69379/35864) is good, but does not explicitly mention `biblatex`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Biblatex` yields the `\citeauthor` and `\Citeauthor` commands, and starred variants.

From the [package's documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (§ 3.8.5, p.97):

> These commands print the authors. Strictly speaking, it prints the labelname list,
> which may be the author, the editor or the translator. \Citeauthor is
> similar to \citeauthor but capitalizes the name prefix of the first name in the
> citation if the useprefix option is enabled, provided that there is a name prefix.
> The starred variants effectively force maxcitenames to 1 for just this command on
> so only print the first name in the labelname list (potentially followed by the “et
> al” string if there are more names).

*Note:*

`biblatex` is not a bibliography engine, and doesn't have to be opposed to `bibtex`. Two bibliography engines can be used with biblatex with the option `backend=`: `biber` and `bibtex`. The default is `biber`, as it has more capabilities than `bibtex`.