# How to mix cite and citeauthor for in-text references

Tags: natbib, templates

I am using a template built on `% ACM Transactions bibliography style (24-Jan-88 version)` for an SCS conference. I am using `\bibliographystyle{scsBiblioStyle}`.

I currently have the citations with `\cite{key}` that results in `[1]` . I want to also be able to use `citeauthor{key}` so at the beginning of a sentence I can have something like `Authors et., al said that` and still end the sentence with `[1]`.

I tried following [How do I cite author in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69379/how-do-i-cite-author-in-latex) for the `citeauthor{}` but this fails as is.  When I add `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`

`LaTeX Error: Command \bibsep already defined.`

When just using `\usepackage{natbib}` I get

`Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.`

I can tell I am mixing/selectively using some of the imports, which I can gander is wrong from it not working. However I don't want to lose the bracket numbered style when using all the options of natbib that I can see.

Is the best way to realistically do this just to manually type the author name reference?

Comment: A short Google search for `scsBiblioStyle` didn't lead me to anything that looked like an official source, but I found the file in some GitHub project. The file there is not compatible with `natbib`'s author-year citation setup, so you simply can not use `natbib`'s author-year module with that style. If you have to stick to the template, it is probably best to stick to the citation style it forces you to use.

Comment: I should add, because it may not be clear, that you can also not use `\citet` in `natbib`'s `numbers` mode with that style, because it relies on the same mechanism as the author-year mode.

Comment: @moewe I see, yes I need to use that template from the conference.  Good to know so I don't keep trying to solve it!